# Python script to generate words

Tags: python

I'm looking to write a short script that will allow me to generate all possible letter combinations with the parameters I set.

For example:

__  **_  _**  n    o

Parameters:

word = 5 letters

4th, 5th letter = n, o

1st letter = any vowel (aeiouy)

2nd, 3rd letter = any letter (abcde...)

in other words, I'm looking to write a script that would return me all 26*26*6 results. It does not matter if it is an actual word (i.e., "zzzno" is fine). And then to generalize it so I can do this with any parameters. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import itertools
import string

letter = string.lowercase
vowel  = "aeiouy"

def all_words(*args):
    return (''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.product(*args))

wordlist = list(all_words(vowel, letter, letter, "n", "o"))
```

returns 4056 entries:

```
['aaano', 'aabno', 'aacno', 'aadno', 'aaeno', 'aafno' ... ]
```

Comment: I keep getting an error saying module attribute has no defined product. Perhaps I'm typing in the arguments incorrectly...

Comment: @David542: Which version of Python are you using? The [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function is available in Python 2.6 and later.

Comment: @Greg: thanks, that explains it -- I had 2.5. How would I do this script without itertools?

Comment: @David542: Look at the documentation for `itertools.product()`, at the code snippet right after it says "This function is equivalent to the following code..."

Answer (score 1):

If you have a word list, you don't even need to write code, you can use grep:

```
$ grep '^[aeiouy][a-z][a-z]no$' /usr/share/dict/words
amino
imino
```