# How can I generate a list of words containing only a specific number of letters in specific positions?

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of all words with certain letters in specific positions, e.g. s, b, a, d or a in position 1, c, w, o, f, b or d at position 2 etc. 
I know which letters can be in which positions, but I don't know how I can generate all possible combinations of these sets of letters in the specific positions.

Comment: Can you tell us what you already tried to do? Which part is not working, give some sample code etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to generate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629395/python-script-to-generate-words)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [6]: from itertools import product

In [7]: [''.join(letters) for letters in product('sbad', 'cwofbd')]
Out[7]: 
['sc',
 'sw',
 'so',
 'sf',
 'sb',
 'sd',
 'bc',
 'bw',
 'bo',
 'bf',
 'bb',
 'bd',
 'ac',
 'aw',
 'ao',
 'af',
 'ab',
 'ad',
 'dc',
 'dw',
 'do',
 'df',
 'db',
 'dd']
```